# Spark for big web applications

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spark-java

I am decided to create a website recently, and I am trying to select programming language and a web template engine for it.
 
First of all, I used Spring Web MVC with Thymleleaf Template Engine. I encountered several problems.

1. Spring is way too slow to use. Any single change takes 30 secs, 1 minute to run web application(If tomcat occurs error, restart needed also) 
2. Thymeleaf engine creates problems with the html templates. It requires Xhtml I suppose and I need to change almost half of the inputs,css,meta etc...
3. Thymeleaf had some problems with static files.
4. ORM and hibernate makes the system even more slow

Secondly, I considered Php to create web application. It is fast to run(almost immidiatly). But does not support MVC(also did not like syntax of it.

I encountered spark java and I really liked syntax and usages. Very similar to node.js and easy to read. But even in the official page It says **framework for minimal web applications.** 
Here is my question, If I use spark for bigger projects, Will it become a problem? I will create almost 10 web pages fully images and user interaction.

Comment: First, Php has frameworks that implement MVC pattern, Second if you gonna use Spark with Microservices archticture it will be very nice and will allow you to scale your website easily

Comment: I want to build whole web page with Spark not just microservisces. And I am a java/android developer so I want to prefer Java platform instead of Laravel etc..

Comment: Spark is amazing for creating small web applications or API backends, but I don't think it has a lot with big one, As docs says it is a micro framework.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried of building a large web application using Spark-java. What is big? Big is relative. What you want is to be able to move fast and leave the framework asap and use your own model and business logic. Spark will allow you to do that. The beauty is that if you decide that Spark doesn't support you enough, you can change to some other tool, your business logic will still be valid and you just change the way you interact with it.